# Comma Separated Numbers For an Axis in Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Is there a way to have Flot make axis numbers be comma-separated?

So for example, instead of 1000000 have 1,000,000

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do that by using the tickFormatter property of the axis.

```
xaxis: {
  tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
    // insert comma logic here and return the string
  }
}
```

Source: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt (under "Customizing the axes")

This page has a function to format numbers with commas: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html

For Example on the yaxis:

```
    $(function () {  
            var plotarea = $("#plotarea");
            $.plot( plotarea , [data], {
                            xaxis: {mode: "time", timeformat: "%m/%d %H:%M:%S"},
                            yaxis: {tickFormatter: function numberWithCommas(x) {
                                      return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                                }
                            },
                            points: { show: true },
                            lines: { show: true, fill: true }

                    } );
    });
```

Comment: I saw this, but wasn't quite clear on how a function operates on it though

Comment: Whenever Flot wants to print the value of a tick for an axis, it will pass the value ('val' up above) and the axis into the function you supply, and it'll use the return value of that function as the label of the tick. Say up above if you replaced the comment with **return "foo"** then all of your tick labels would be "foo"

Comment: And axis should be 'x' or 'y'?

Comment: Depends on which axis you want to format. If it's both, then you'll want to set this property on both axes.

Comment: Oh, I'm being dense. I didn't realize that this went within the `xaxis:` or `yaxis:`. Updated your post with a working complete example for the yaxis.