# Flotchart format axis values

Tags: php, jquery-plugins

I am using [Flotcharts](http://www.flotcharts.org/) with **PHP**. I am facing two issues

1. I want to represents numbers in well format on Y-axis like **1500** must be shown as **1,500** and so on. I knows php function `number_format()` but if I passed `number_format()` while plotting chart firebug throws parsing errors. Please see the code below under heading **ISSUE-1** and check `echo number_format(6443.230356)`
2. If value for Y-axis is from (**1 to 9**) then currently it is showing as (**1, 2 .. 9**). I want to represent these values like (**1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ... 9.0**)

**ISSUE-1**

```
<script>
plotOptions = {
"colors":["#edaf40","#999","#edaf3e","#ec8","#9cc","#dad","#9ce","#fca"],
"grid":{
"labelMargin":0,
"tickColor":"#e3e3e3",
"backgroundColor":"#f2f2f2",
"borderWidth":0.5,
"hoverable":true,
"autoHighlight":true,
"clickable":false,
"color":"#bbb"
},
"bars": { show: true, barWidth: 0.85, series_spread: true, align: "center","lineWidth": 0.3,fillColor:{colors: [ { opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 1 } ] } },
"lines":{"show":false,"lineWidth":1.25,"fill":0},
"points":{"show":false,"radius":2,"lineWidth":2,"fill":1},
"shadowSize":1,
"yaxis":{"min":0,"max":<?php echo number_format(6443.230356)?>,axisLabel: '',axisLabelUseCanvas: false,axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',axisLabelPadding: 5},
"xaxis":{"min":"1989","max":"2016","tickSize":5,"tickLength": 0, "ticks": 0.1},
zoom: {
interactive: true
}
};
</script>
```

[image]

I also tried `"max":'<?php echo number_format(6443.230356)?>'` but this time firebug said not a number error.

```
NaN
```

and also

[image]

I searched their site but not found the solution. Please guide how to solve.

To fix **point 2** I tried

```
function suffixFormatter(val) {
    if (val >= 1)
        return val.toFixed(yaxis.tickDecimals) + " 0";
    else if (val <= 9)
        return val.toFixed(yaxis.tickDecimals) + " 0";
    else  
        return val;
}

"yaxis":{"function":suffixFormatter(<?php echo $min_val;?>), "min":<?php echo $min_val;?>,"max":<?php echo (1.2*$yaxismax);?>,axisLabel: '<?=$indicatorData[0]->unit?>',axisLabelUseCanvas: false,axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',axisLabelPadding: 5},
```

but error occur `yaxis is not define` `tickDecimals is not define`.

I am really diss heart with the **FlotChart** support it is very very poor no proper example code no proper guide. Please somebody guide me?

Comment: Maybe it can be because the "max" and "min" accept only integer numbers, or not with so many numbers after the comma.

Comment: and what about the second issue

Comment: Here's for the first issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5968333/851045

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a comma in the number, so the "max" property have the value "6" and then the comma close the "max" property. so the program read 443 as another property name, and then it looks for a ":", but only another comma is given...

So, after all, i think the numbers can only be integers or with a point instead of the comma, as a comma close the property value field.

Comment: and what about the second issue?

Comment: Are you writing that `ctx.createLinearGradient(0, top, 0, bottom)` ? Because createLinearGradient accept four nubmers as parameters, check what "top" and "bottom" contains

Answer (score 0):

For your second issue – set the `tickDecimals` option.

Comment: I read & find function formatter(val, axis) {
    return val.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals);
} but there is no example where to call this function can you please re-edit my script
"yaxis":{"min":0,"max":<?php echo number_format(6443.230356)?>,axisLabel: '',axisLabelUseCanvas: false,axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',axisLabelPadding: 5},